# configure showing issue with tcl

Tags: c++, tcl, configure

While configure a tool I am getting this error. Any idea about this ?

```
checking for Tcl_CreateInterp in -ltcl... no
checking for Tcl_CreateInterp in -ltcl8.6... no
checking for Tcl_CreateInterp in -ltcl86... no
configure: error: cannot build without tcl8.*
```

Comment: One of those should have worked. Please describe more about your system configuration...

Comment: I am using AIX 6.1

Comment: Hmm. What does `config.log` say? (Don't post the whole of it; it'll be thousands of lines long, most of which we don't care for at all. Look for the bits that mention `Tcl_CreateInterp` and `-ltcl` and so on.) It's possible that the real issue is that the libraries are absent or not on your library linker path…

Comment: lslpp -l|grep tcl
  tcl.base                   8.4.7.0  COMMITTED  Binary executable files of Tcl
  tcl.man.en_US              8.4.7.0  COMMITTED  Tcl man page documentation

Comment: configure:8009: checking for Tcl_CreateInterp in -ltcl8.5 configure:8044: cc -qlanglvl=extc89 -o conftest -Incurses/v5.9/include -Incurses/v5.9/include/ncurses/ -Incurses/v5.9/include -I ncurses/v5.9/include/ncurses/ conftest.c -ltcl8.5 >&5 ld: 0706-006 Cannot find or open library file: -l tcl8.5 ld:open(): No such file or directory configure:8051: $? = 255 configure: failed program was:

Comment: Here are ny env variable to pick tcl8.5:

echo $LDFLAGS "-Ltcltk/v8.5b3/lib"
echo 4LIBPATH "-Ltcltk/v8.5b3/lib"